# Cloud Page - Security Headers

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, landing-page, unsubscribe

Good morning,
I have built 2 cloud pages to manage the unsubscription process of contacts.
As suggested by Salesforce's best practices (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_cloud_pages_security_best_practices.htm&type=5), I put the following script for the security header in the cloud page code, but this breaks the images and the font.

---

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Strict-Transport-Security","max-age=200");
  Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-XSS-Protection","1; mode=block");
  Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-Frame-Options","Deny");
  Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff");
  Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Referrer-Policy","strict-origin-when-cross-origin");
  Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Content-Security-Policy","default-src 'self'");
  </script>
```

---

Why does this problem occur?

Comment: Please remember and go through your questions, marking good answers accepted, as described in [this article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing quotes around *server*.
Try replacing your first line with this:

```
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">
```

Comment: I have the same problem and `<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">` adding this didn't help. @lukaslunow

Answer (score 0):

The code from the documentation is just an example of header, if images or CSS are on your page then you need to update this header to accept it.

So the issue is with this header :

**Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Content-Security-Policy","default-src 'self'");**

If you are using image from content builder your header can be like this:

**Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; img-src https://image.s7.sfmc-content.com 'self';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';");**

However you may need to change the domain in the header based on the images from each page.